# Ruby on Rails - save 3 values with one times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, image, store

I'm newer in Ruby on Rails. Now I want to save 3 images with one times in controller. I'm researched more in internet but I still not found answer and don't know how to do it?

- My database have some fields: id (int), product_id (int), link_photo (text)

It's mean with one ID of product I can store 3 records of images (3 rows in database for one product)

- In view layer, I had input to upload files

> ```
>         <div class="form-group <%= has_error?(@photo,"link_photo") %>">
>           <label for="pictures"><%= I18n.t("farms.pictures") %></label>
>           <%= file_field :photo, :link_photo_first, class:"filestyle", accept:"image/png,image/jpeg" %><br/>
>           <%= file_field :photo, :link_photo_second, class:"filestyle", accept:"image/png,image/jpeg" %><br/>
>           <%= file_field :photo, :link_photo_third, class:"filestyle", accept:"image/png,image/jpeg" %>
>         </div>
> ```

- In controller:

  ```
    # Save the first photo
    if !params[:photo][:link_photo_first].nil?
      @photo.link_photo = params[:photo][:link_photo_first]
      @photo.save
    end

    # Save the second photo
    if !params[:photo][:link_photo_second].nil?
      @photo.link_photo = params[:photo][:link_photo_second]
      @photo.save
    end

    # Save the third photo
    if !params[:photo][:link_photo_third].nil?
      @photo.link_photo = params[:photo][:link_photo_third]
      @photo.save
    end
  ```

But if code like above it's can stored only one record at first.
Please help me how to save it 3 images above. Thanks!

======================

**UPDATE:**

Thanks everybody for reply. I knew the cause of it is: it's need renew again the @photo variable before save in next times.
Maybe have many solutions to resolve it, but I edited like bellow and it's can run OK:

**Fix like bellow: add @photo = Photo.create before save**

> ## Save the first photo
>
> ```
>       if !params[:photo][:link_photo_first].nil?
>         @photo = Photo.create
>         @photo.product_id = @product.id
>         @photo.link_photo = params[:photo][:link_photo_first]
>         @photo.save
>       end
>
>       # Save the second photo
>       if !params[:photo][:link_photo_second].nil?
>         @photo = Photo.create
>         @photo.product_id = @product.id
>         @photo.link_photo = params[:photo][:link_photo_second]
>         @photo.save
>       end
>
>       # Save the third photo
>       if !params[:photo][:link_photo_third].nil?
>         @photo = Photo.create
>         @photo.product_id = @product.id
>         @photo.link_photo = params[:photo][:link_photo_third]
>         @photo.save
>       end
> ```

Comment: need to show your model here. Can a photo have 3 `link_photo` ?

Comment: Why you not use nested form?, you can watch [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) episode on railscasts

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't change `@photo` variable, which means you override same row after each `.save` action. What you need to do, is to initialize new model instance each time, eg

```
  # Save the first photo
  if !params[:photo][:link_photo_first].nil?
    @photo = YourModel.new(params)
    @photo.link_photo = params[:photo][:link_photo_first]
    @photo.save
  end

  # Save the second photo
  if !params[:photo][:link_photo_second].nil?
    @photo = YourModel.new(params)
    @photo.link_photo = params[:photo][:link_photo_second]
    @photo.save
  end

  # Save the third photo
  if !params[:photo][:link_photo_third].nil?
    @photo = YourModel.new(params)
    @photo.link_photo = params[:photo][:link_photo_third]
    @photo.save
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. You right. And I updated my code like above!